# SD Card Slot not recognized 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dell, sd-card, xps, micro-sd

I hope somone can help me out. I tried some solutions but nothing has fixed my problems.

My SD Card Slot is not recognized by Ubuntu. It also doesnt listed as a storage. 
I dont know how i should fix this problem, because i am a newbie in the Linux scene.

I thank you for your great help

Comment: It that a working slot?

Comment: yeah it should be. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 vor a few weeks. before that i used windows 10. with ubuntu i cant recognize the slot

Comment: What brand/model of Notebook (or PC)? Is it a **SD** or **microSD** card slot (or both)?

Comment: I have a Ultrabook XP13 6500 from DELL, and it is a SD card slot. I use  a micro sd with an  SD card adapter for micro sd.